# MySQL Community Server vs MySQL Clustor Community Server

Tags: mysql

Which MySQL version of server will be the right choice if we are using a server of clusters?
Will it get the GPL version of cluster server of MySQL? I found that MySQL cluster will be available as commercial and GPL. What are the feature limitation of GPL version and what will be the price of commercial edition?

Comment: Should be moved to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mchl: No - is too discursive for most SE sites, so it would be closed there too (Not Constructive) - so we should close it here instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no feature differences between GPL and commercial licenses. The difference is in (obviously) licesne terms, and in support you get.